# What is the equivalent of an "outer join" in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Say I have a Prolog db

```
person(john).
person(jane).
person(mike).

favourite_icecream(john,strawberry).
favourite_icecream(jane,choc_chip).

favourite_colour(jane,green).
favourite_colour(mike,red).
```

How can I get the equivalent of an outer-join to get a series of results like

```
john, strawberry, _
jane, choc_chip, green
mike, _, red
```

Comment: Prolog just doesn't work this way. Relational database semantics are not the same as Prolog semantics.

Answer (score 3):

You can approximate the behaviour of (a specific) SQL query in this way:

```
?- person(P),(favourite_icecream(P,I)->true;I='?'),(favourite_colour(P,C)->true;C='?').
P = john,
I = strawberry,
C = ? ;
P = jane,
I = choc_chip,
C = green ;
P = mike,
I = ?,
C = red.
```

Clearly, not a very attractive syntax... could be made better for specific use cases, but the effort to generalize is probably not worth it.

As Daniel suggested, Prolog mindset (tuple oriented) is not the same of SQL (recordset oriented).

*edit*

My answer needs an improvement: let's say a person has more that 1 preference. Just to say, change the DB to

```
...
favourite_icecream(john,strawberry).
favourite_icecream(john,lemon).
...
```

The query above would yield only the first preference. Using a so called [soft-cut](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(*-%3E)/2) instead of the [if-then-else](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2) we can better model the outer join:

```
outer_join(P,I,C) :-
    person(P),
    (favourite_icecream(P,I)*->true;I='?'),
    (favourite_colour(P,C)*->true;C='?').
```

Comment: It would be cleaner to write `I = (?)` in place of `I = '?'`